# Cosa significa «si fosse risoluta» in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

C'è una frase da Luigi Pirandello [tratta](https://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Il_fu_Mattia_Pascal/4) da *Il fu Mattia Pascal*:

> Ma io so ch’egli *(Malagna)* desiderava con tutto il cuore dalla moglie un certo compenso alle afflizioni senza fine che gli procurava; desiderava cioè che ella *(Guendalina, cioè la moglie)* un bel giorno si fosse risoluta a mettergli al mondo un figliuolo.

Ho trovato nel vocabolario Treccani [tre significati](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/risolvere) per il verbo pronominale «risolversi» che potrebbero entrarci, almeno teoricamente: *a) prendere una decisione, decidersi per una soluzione; b) evolvere verso la guarigione, riferito a processi morbosi; c) semplificare, chiarire qualcosa di complicato, difficile, oscuro*. Il significato «a» mi pare il più probabile, ma a dire il vero, nessuno di loro sembra molto adeguato. La moglie di Malagna è malata, ma il significato «b» riferisce a «processi morbosi», mentre lei è una persona, non un processo. Sono anche confuso perché la parola «risoluta» è un aggettivo, non un participio passato, ma qui è usata con la particella pronominale come se fosse un verbo vero e proprio.

Potreste spiegarmi questa frase? Molte grazie!

Comment: "Risoluta" è qui participio passato: siccome i tempi composti di "risolversi" (usato intransitivamente) si coniugano con l'ausiliare "essere", il participio passato si deve concordare con il soggetto.

Comment: @Charo grazie, ho creduto che il participio passato fosse "risolto" e "risoluto" un latinismo senza questo valore, ritengo i miei occhi colpevoli. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il significato che si adatta al contesto da te citato è quello indicato dalla a), cioè prendere una decisione, decidersi per una soluzione.

> desiderava cioè che ella (*Guendalina*, cioè la moglie) un bel giorno si
>   fosse ***decisa*** a mettergli al mondo un figliuolo.

Comment: Grazie di cuore, la tua confirmazione mi è stata molto utile. :)